# How should I correct the registerations of my Scoped Services in my Blazor server app after upgrading to Visual Studio 2022 and .NET 6?

Tags: c#, service, migration, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server app that is built on .NET Core 3.1. The app is working without problem.

After I updated from VS 2019 to VS 2022 and also .NetCore3.1 to Net6.0 I noticed that my scoped services are not running any more. I have read that the registration of the services are a little bit different in .NET6.0, but I couldn't make it working.

My actual registration is in Startup.cs (that is merged with Program.cs in .NET6.0 as I understood)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddScoped<ConnectService>();
        services.AddScoped<TagService>();       
        
    }
```

I tried to register in Pogram.cs like below but didn't work

```
   public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
        builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<ConnectService>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<TagService>();       
    }
```

I am injecting the service in my razor page as follows (that I haven't changed)

```
@page "/connect2"
@inject TagService TagService
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the basic structure with the templated solution.

```
dotnet new blazorserver -o <OutputDirectory>
```

It should look something like this

```
//declare web 
var builder = WebApplication.CreateDefault(args)

//add services
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ConnectService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<TagService>();

//then build app
var app = builder.Build();

//add any neccessary routing middleware

//then run
app.Run()
```